# Image of $\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $5$ and $H$ a group of order $10$. Let $\phi : G → H$ be a group homomorphism s.t for some $g ∈ G, \phi(g) \neq 1$ (identity). Prove the image of $\phi$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.

I know that $\mathrm{im}(\phi)$ is a subgroup of $H$ and can show that, but I don't know how to prove it is normal. I may need to use the sentence 'Let $G$ be a group of order $5$ and $H$ a group of order $10$' to prove that though..

Comment: You should split this into multiple questions.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Also, please, post only one question in one post. Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: since $\mathrm{im}(\phi)$ is a subgroup of $H$, $\mathrm{im}(\phi)$ has order $1, 2$ or $5$ by Lagrange. Since $\phi$ is not a trivial homomorphism, the only possibilities are $2$ or $5$. If $|\mathrm{im}(\phi)| = 5$, then $\mathrm{im}(\phi)$ has index $2$ in $H$, hence must be normal. Can you show that $|\mathrm{im}(\phi)|$ cannot be $2$? (Think about the kernel/first isomorphism theorem)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I don't know whether it's proper reason but, by the first isomorphism theorem, |G|/|{0}| = |im(ϕ)| so |im(ϕ)| must be 5 then, as you said, index is 2 then it is normal, which also I've learnt in the lecture. Thanks.

Comment: @mathstock: by the first isomorphism theorem $|G| = |\ker(\phi)||\mathrm{im}(\phi)|$, so in particular $|\mathrm{im}(\phi)| \mid |G|$. But otherwise, your reasoning is sound. Glad I could help, and let me know if you have any further questions!